# Python: incorporate git repo in project

Tags: python, git, pip

What is best practice for incorporating git repositories into the own project which do **not** contain a setup.py? There are several ways that I could imagine, but it doesn't seem clear which is best.

1. Copy the relevant code and include it into the own project

   **pro:**

   - Only use the relevant code,

   **con:**

   - git repo might be updated
   - need to do this for every project again
   - feels like stealing
2. Cloning the repository and writing a setup.py and install it with pip

   **pro:**

   - easy
   - package can be updated
   - can use package like any *normal* pip package

   **con:**

   - feels weird
3. Clone the repository and add the path to the project's search path

   **pro:**

   - easy
   - package can be updated

   **con:**

   - needing to adjust the search path also feels strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you forgot the best option: Ask the original project maintainer to make the package available via `pip`. Since `pip` can install directly from git repositories this doesn't take more than a `setup.py` -- in particular, you don't need a PyPI account, you don't need to tag releases, etc.

If that's not possible then I would opt for your second option, i.e. provide my own `setup.py` file in a fork of the project. This makes incorporating upstream changes pretty easy (basically you simply `git pull` them from the upstream repo) and gives you all the benefits of package management (automatic installation, dependency management, etc.).

Comment: I was thinking about implementations of Neural Network architectures. And normally there are a bunch of different projects/repos implementing them. I think asking them to provide it via pip would clutter PyPl quickly (concerning that aspect)

Comment: As I wrote, installation via `pip` does *not* require a registration of the package on PyPI -- `pip` installs packages from git repositories perfectly fine. Aside from that, I don't think cluttering PyPI is an issue if people stick to suitable package names.